# Apple Metal MPSImage memory layout

Tags: ios, metal

I'm having trouble working with the underlying memory of an MPSImage. I've been using the methods `getBytes` and `replace` on MPSImage's `texture` member variable to read and write the underlying data. The problem is I can't find documentation of how the memory is interpreted as an image (i.e. how the rows, columns, and channels are layed out). Part of what complicates the issue is that regardless of the number of feature channels, the data is stored as a stack of RGBA texture slices, with some channels possibly left unused. For instance, with 3 feature channels, there will be one RGBA texture slice, and one channel's worth of space will be left unused.

The problem is, how is the MPSImage data actually arranged within the texture? It seems more complicated than I originally would have guessed.

After much experimentation, it seems like the data is arranged differently depending on whether the number of feature channels is < 4 or > 4. But I'm still having trouble figuring it out.

Can anyone explain the MPSImage data layout to me?

Answer (score 1):

The first four feature channels are encoded as they would be for a standard RGBA texture. Feature channel 0 is in the "R" position, feature channel 1 is in the "G" position and so forth.

The next four feature channels are present as the next slice in a texture2d_array. If you have a 100x100 image with 20 feature channels, this will be encoded as a 100x100 texture array with (20/4=) 5 slices in the array.

To make matters more complicated, you can have MPSImage arrays with have multiple images in them, each with more than 4 feature channels. This is frequently referred to as batching.  The second image is found in the texture array immediately after the first image. If we have multiple 100x100x20 images in the MPSImage, then the second one starts at slice 5, the third one at slice 10 and so forth.